# Black background wouldn't appear when checked in active

Tags: css

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpavuct4/)

HTML

```
<div class="list current">
<div class="checked current active">
</div>
<input id="hi" type="checkbox" name="id" value="hi" class="box"><label for="hi" style="margin-bottom: 30px; width: 100px; height: 100px" class="name checked">hihi</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.list input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
.list input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.list.current .box:checked + .name:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 72px;
  left: 72px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 3;
}

.checked.current:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  transition: opacity .3s;
  z-index: 10;
}

.checked.current.active:before{
  opacity: 1;
}

.name{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

This is a brief example. Struggled to have background black with opacity 0.85 appear (checked current active) when click on checkbox, covering text "hihi". But wasn't able to get it working. Not sure why :before is not working.

[image: Kitten example]

**UPDATED HTML/CSS**

Still couldn't make it work together with black background and tick center on that black background. When click, nothing happens :(

Comment: Only problem with black stuff, or issue iwth any other property/css apply?

Comment: @Krekkon - only problem is black because let's say when click on image for example, input will be checked and then image is covered with opacity in black background and tick on black background. So far I got tick working but not black background

Comment: .checked.current.active has no height or positioning.  But what do you want to have happen? Can you explain what you want to see?

Comment: @jme11 -- class list has aspect ratio with padding top 110% so that label will display the background image. then when check the checkbox, the background image will be covered with black background in 0.85 opacity and tick image will be on black background. image and tick appears just fine, but not black background. hmm.

Comment: @jme11 see the example picture - you see three layers: kitten, opacity and tick

Comment: Here's a simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/Lpavuct4/3/.  Need to jam.  If this is what you want, I will post explanation later.

Comment: @jme11 yes it is exactly what i m looking for - thanks. but does it work for image? because after image, the layer will have opacity black background in same div. I will try to work and see if it works

Comment: @jme11 - thanks again and I managed to make it work as the way I wanted it to do. But still before and after confuse me sometimes. Appreciate your help and explanation

Comment: The problem isn't that `:before` is not working. The problem is neither your `.current.active` element nor its `:before` pseudo-element have any height nor content. So you don't see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your two examples, I think that some of the source of confusion might be simply from the complexity your css and markup.  Here's a simplified implementation of the cat example:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpavuct4/7/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
            <div class="ratio-4-3">
                <div class="inner">
                    <input id="kitty" type="checkbox" class="productBox" />
                    <label for="kitty" class="productName">
                        <img src="http://funnyanimalpictures.funnypicturesutopia.com/pics/16/A-Small-Ball-Of-Kitty-Cat.jpg" class="img-responsive" /> 
                    </label>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
            <div class="ratio-4-3">
                <div class="inner">
                    <input id="kitty1" type="checkbox" class="productBox" />
                    <label for="kitty1" class="productName">
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/720/540" class="img-responsive" /> 
                    </label>                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
            <div class="ratio-4-3">
                <div class="inner">
                    <input id="kitty3" type="checkbox" class="productBox" />
                    <label for="kitty3" class="productName">
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/750/750" class="img-responsive" /> 
                    </label>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
            <div class="ratio-4-3">
                <div class="inner">
                    <input id="kitty4" type="checkbox" class="productBox" />
                    <label for="kitty4" class="productName">
                        <img src="http://placekitten.com/700/650" class="img-responsive" /> 
                    </label>                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
[class^="col"] {
    padding-bottom: 30px; /*Balance the grid gutters with 30px of padding below the images*/
}
.ratio-4-3 { /*Create the intrinsic wrapper*/
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    height: 0;
}
.inner { /*Create an inner wrap for the content*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden; /*Hide anything that falls outside the inner wrap*/
}
.productBox {
    position: absolute; /*Take the checkbox out of the document flow*/
    right: 100%;
    visibility: hidden; /*Hide the checkbox*/
}
.productName {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.productName:before {  
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;    
}
.productBox:checked + .productName:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
.productBox:checked + .productName:after {
    content:'✔';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: green;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

I did some things differently than you did.  First, while I used an intrinsic ratio for the columns, the technique I used allows you to add your images into your markup without having them be background images.  This can be beneficial on two fronts.  One is that you can get the benefit of image SEO, if that's important to you.  The second is that it keeps your markup nice and clean (no inline styles needed).  This is important when it comes to maintenance.  This technique is adapted from the A List Apart article example #2 found **[here](http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/)**.

As for implementing the checkbox feature, I also adapted the order of the markup, wrapping the image inside of the label. This is more semantic in my opinion because the image IS your label.  This also makes it very simple to add the before and after pseudo elements. And, it simplifies your markup and css, which again is essential in terms of maintainability.

The application of the before and after pseudo elements is not that complicated.  You just have to remember a couple of things.  First is that you have to have a content property (even if it's empty).  You had that already.  Second is stacking order.  Using z-index is one way to handle this, but you can also rely on [the natural stacking order of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index).  In this case, because both the before and after elements have positioning, they will appear "above" the root element that doesn't have positioning, with the before element (naturally) below the the after element.

Finally, ***and this was your main issue***, you have to make sure that since you are using positioning, the positioned element has to have an element against which to position itself.  While you correctly set your root element to have positioning using the position property set to relative, that element had no height.  It was a collapsed div. So, when you set the positioned element to block, it was 100% width but 0 height.

In the case of the demo, the `label` element gets its height from the image that it contains.  Therefore, when you set the top/left/right/bottom properties all to 0 for the `.productName:before`, it entirely covers the image.

By the way, in case you're confused about the **[label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)** element **for** attribute, it points to the **id** of the element to which it is bound.  This is important for this technique to work!  In your example, you seem to have the value set on the checkbox to kitty, so I think you might be under the assumption that that is how you create the connection between those two elements.  While it might not matter if you've only got one checkbox/label pair on the page, that's not going to work once you add a couple of additional checkboxes.

Hope this explanation helped and it wasn't TL;DR.